# Partitioning nightmare with USB Windows installation

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, rufus

Finally able to boot from external USB using Rufus but only after I had formatted it using MBR-NFTS.

However, now when I boot the .iso from my usb and try to install Windows I get an error saying "Windows cannot be installed to this disk. The selected disk is of the GPT partition style."

Windows WAS installed before on the GPT partitioned disk. The reason I am re installing is because my Windows install became corrupted after an accidental partial format.

I've already disabled Secure Boot and enabled CSM in BIOS.

My understanding is that I have 2 options

1- Use Diskpart to erase existing partitions on the target drive and reformat using MBR.

2- Try again with Rufus creating an install USB using GPT-UEFI FAT32 formatting.
I've already tried # 2 unsuccessfully several times.

My question is if I proceed with option 1 will it create any compatibility issues?
I have 2 separate drives, one dedicated to Linux-Ubuntu and the other Windows.
Can the same UEFI BIOS manage 2 different OS's, drives with different partitioning schemes, ie will I have any issues switching between boot drives?

Thanks for any feedback.

Comment: " MBR-NFTS." this is your problem, it needs to be a gpt partiton not mbr.

Comment: Yes but as mentioned this was what i tried first. I then got an error saying i had to enable CSM in BIOS which I did but it made no difference. My question remains- Can or should I simply reformat the target drive as MBR?

Comment: MBR, yes if is 2tb or less

Comment: ok, used diskpart to convert mbr. Now new issue. see https://superuser.com/questions/1594537/windows-cannnot-be-installed-after-using-diskpart-to-convert-to-mbr