# Windows cannnot be installed after using Diskpart to convert to MBR

Tags: partitioning, mbr, windows-installation, gpt, secure-boot

ok so long story short simply trying to reinstall Windows 10 on a disk in a dual boot setup  (Linux is on a physically separate drive and launches without issue).
First issue was when using Rufus USB to install was told that the target disk needed to be MBR partition type (see [Partitioning nightmare with USB Windows installation](https://superuser.com/questions/1594395/partitioning-nightmare-with-usb-windows-installation)). All of my drives originally had GPT partitioning.

So I used Diskpart from cmd line to convert just the Windows disk (Drive 1 in attached image) to MBR.
But now when I attempt to install I get the following error popup.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKyiy.jpg

Does this mean I cannot use MBR partitioning at all? As mentioned in previous post I've already disabled Secure Boot and enabled CSM in UEFI-BIOS.
Any feedback appreciated!

Comment: If the drive is over 2TB in size you must use GPT partition.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Partitioning nightmare with USB Windows installation](https://superuser.com/questions/1594395/partitioning-nightmare-with-usb-windows-installation)

Comment: Not sure why you are linking to my previous question which I have already linked to in my post. Could you be a little more specific? Can I use MBR in my situation? It was suggested that I should. And if not how do i overcome the "Windows cannot be installed to this disk. The selected disk is of the GPT partition style." error message? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are sample scripts by Microsoft for creating partitions for different scenarios. They are given here: [Sample scripts](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/windows-deployment-sample-scripts-sxs#createpartitions-scripts)

It also explains the required partition layout for Windows. The scripts take into account the required partition layout.
You can use one of them to suit your requirement.